# Contentful GraphQL endpoint: how to retrieve all entries of a content type

Tags: graphql, contentful

```
{
  Post {
      name
  }
}
```

While trying to retrieve all the entries on a content type, it only gives error of:

```
"Argument \"id\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided."
```

Since `id` field is required. How do I get all entries of a content type then?

Ref: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From docs [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/schema-generation):

> The produced Query object exposes two fields that you can use to query content of that type: one to fetch individual content documents (`friendlyUser` in the example) and another to do queries over all the content of the type (`friendlyUserCollection`).

So for any resource that you want to retrieve all entries of, you need to append `Collection` at the end of its id, then use `items` field to retrieve all entries. As in:

```
{
  PostCollection {
      items {
          name
      }
  }
}
```

Apart from docs, you can also view all available resources at corresponding GraphiQL instance here, which could be pretty useful:

`https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/{SPACE_ID}/explore?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`

Search or select `Query` to see all schemas:

[image: GraphiQL]

Answer (score 0):

Having agreed that the right way to filter Post's is to query for a PostCollection, there are a few parameters that may come handy:

```
{
  PostCollection(limit: 30) {
      items {
          name
          text
      }
  }
}
```

Having an idea of the size of the collection, this one limits the back-end resources that the query will allocate.
By default the size is 100 and if the collection contains only a few elements, not specifying the limit is a waste of resources.

```
{
  PostCollection(where: { topic: "politics" }) {
      items {
          name
          text
      }
  }
}
```

This one will retrieve only the posts with a certain topic field (obviously, the field must be present in the content type and be filled in the contents).

There are a [lot of other possibilities](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/graphql/#/reference/collection-filters/limitations).

Answer (score -1):

#### Query a single `id`

I think you can try this in the GraphQL playgound
`http://localhost:8000/___graphql`

```
query PostById($id: String!) {
  contentfulPost(id: { eq: $id }) {
    name
  }
}
```

and add a QUERY VARIABLE

```
{
  "id": "my-awesome-id"
}
```

#### Query all the `Posts`

> How do I get all entries of a content type then?

As already mentioned in the accepter answer, in the GraphQL playground app, you shall be able to do the following:

```
{
  PostCollection {
    items {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer regarding the query variable is off-topic, because the OP is not interested in runtime filtering. The answer about retrieving all the posts is completely wrong. Correcting it along the lines of the accepted answer.